# Error while fetching value of rich text area on console log in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to fetch the value of rich text area from **home.html**, but I am getting an error.

**Home.html** code as follows :

```
<ion-content>
    <rich-text [formControlItem]="item" placeholderText="A sample of placeholder text"></rich-text>

    <div padding [innerHTML]="item.value" ></div>
    <button ion-button (click)="abc(item)"></button>
</ion-content>
```

**Home.ts** code as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  item: FormControl;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ionViewWillLoad() {
    this.item = this.formBuilder.control('');
  }

  abc(item)
  {
    console.log("HELLO");
    console.log(item,"ITEM");
  }
}
```

Error I am getting when I click the button to fetch the value:

[image]

How can I fetch the rich text area's value in the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the brackets for `abc(item)` method it should be like this :

```
abc(item){
    console.log("HELLO");
    console.log(item.value,"ITEM");
  }
```

Comment: item.value should be added in .ts

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use it like this

```
<ion-content>
    <rich-text [(ngModel)]="item" name="item" placeholderText="A sample of placeholder text"></rich-text>
    <div padding [innerHTML]="item.value" ></div>
    <button ion-button (click)="abc(item)"></button>    
</ion-content>
```

The `ngModel` is use for two way data binding for more information refer this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/forms/)